# Transfer whole schema from Oracle to Hive

Tags: oracle, hive, hdfs, sqoop

Oracle database has multiple schemas. How can I import all tables into Hive from only the default schema using sqoop import-all-tables

```
sqoop import-all-tables --verbose --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@XX.XX.XX.XX:1234:SID/Schema_Name
--username USER --password PWD --hive-overwrite --hive-import
```

Where can I specify the schema name to download all 70 tables from that particular schema only? Thanks for your help and inputs.
Error Log:

> 16/12/15 06:47:20 DEBUG manager.OracleManager: No connection paramenters specified. Using regular API for making connection.
>   16/12/15 06:47:20 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question. Questions like "how to do this" without showing any attempt or effort are usually not welcome here.

Comment: have you tried some sample code. please post it.

Comment: Here is the sample code

Comment: sqoop import-all-tables --verbose --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@XX.XX.XX.XX:1621:SID \
--username USER --password PWD --hive-overwrite --hive-import

Comment: I am not able to provide the schema name in the URL, it shows null exception error. Need to import all tables from the one particular schema which has 70 tables

Comment: @johnkiran Correct me if I am wrong. As per my understanding, users and schemas are essentially the same thing. Is `USER` the name of schema here?

Answer (score 0):

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoop jdbc:oracle:thin:@//your-ip:1521 --username root --password hadoop --target-dir '/Sqoop/AllTables'
```

also please follow documentation for [importing all table](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_all_tables_literal)

Comment: Thanks. I did try, but I am not able to specify the particular schema name in the URL, from where I want to download all the 70 tables